# Mixing JDK/JRE Hotspot/OpenJ9

Tags: java

I'm wondering if it matters to use the same JRE as the JDK that was used for compilation.

For example I compile with OpenJ9(v12) then run my server with Hotspot(v12).

What kind of problem can arise? What about performance?

Should I prefer

- JDK OpenJ9/JRE OpenJ9
- JDK Hotspot/JRE Hotspot

Or can I mix
 - JDK OpenJ9/JRE Hotspot
 - JDK Hotspot/JRE OpenJ9

Would performance be impacted by JRE only? or both ?

Comment: Bytecode is bytecode, isn't it?

Comment: @LutzHorn is it? So you're saying both JDK are generating the same bytecode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenJ9 and Hotspot are 2 implementation of Java virtual machine (JVM), JVM in turn is a part of a JDK

JDK OpenJ9 and JDK Hotspot are OpenJDK packed with different JVMs, it must be true that both generate same bytecodes: [oj9_faq](https://www.eclipse.org/openj9/oj9_faq.html)

The different between them is how they run bytecode, in short there are 3 differents

- Command line options
- Garbage controller policy
- Code that use com.sun.management interfaces

[moving-to-openjdk-with-eclipse-openj9](https://blog.openj9.org/2019/02/26/moving-to-openjdk-with-eclipse-openj9/)

Performance impact can only determined by trying, it depends on the nature of your application.

Comment: Ok so if I understand, JDK and JRE stays the same (OpenJDK), they 'just' provide a different JVM that will run the bytecode differently.

Answer (score 0):

You should expect the two JDKs to generate the same bytecode because they both use the the same java compiler from OpenJDK. The differences, as lolacoco said, will be at runtime due to differing VM and GC implementations. Even if you generated the bytecode with a different compiler (e.g. the one in the eclipse IDE), that bytecode should run on any VM.